# How to set subfig options independently from caption options

Tags: fonts, captions, subfloats, small-caps

My aim is to set the font style for **caption** labels as small caps and for **sub-caption** labels as normal.

But apparently the option `sc` of the package `caption` also trickles down into sub-captions..

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[font={rm,md,up},margin=10pt,singlelinecheck=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
  \caption{Subfigures}
\subfloat[Subfigure 1]
{
{
somepicture
}
}
\subfloat[Subfigure 2]
{
{
somepicture
}
}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Which outputs

[image]

where both (a) and (b) are in small caps.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `labelfont=normal` option to the subfig package declaration as follows:

```
\usepackage[font={rm,md,up},labelfont=normal,margin=10pt,singlelinecheck=false]{subfig}
```

[image: Example]